# React calculator too many renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a calculator. The issue is, I am trying to do something like `1 + 3` for example, and although I can display the 1 and 3, I can't put the '+' in between them (operation), I tried adding an `onClick` and it gives to many re-renders.

I tried `onClick={sum}`, and `onClick={() => sum()}` and even `onClick={(e) => sum(e)}` to then use `e.preventDefault()` on my sum function but it keeps giving the same error, it does not do it.

I know that if it was an input field an `onChange` would easily do it, but with q button that `onChange` is not an option, so I am stuck.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

    const Calculator = () => {
      const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState('')
      const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState('')
      const [operation, setOperation] = useState('')
      const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    
      function sum() {
        // e.preventDefault()
        setOperation('+')
      }
    
      function clear() {
        setFirstValue('')
        setSecondValue('')
        setOperation('')
      }
    
      // useEffect(() => {
      // }, [operation, firstValue, secondValue, value])
    
      if (operation === "+") {
        setValue(parseInt(firstValue) + parseInt(secondValue))
      }
      if (operation === "-") {
        setValue(parseInt(firstValue) - parseInt(secondValue))
      }
      if (operation === "x") {
        setValue(parseInt(firstValue) * parseInt(secondValue))
      }
      if (operation === "/") {
        setValue(parseInt(firstValue) / parseInt(secondValue))
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="calculator">
          <div data-testid="name">Calculator</div>
    
          <div data-testid="display" className="display">{firstValue} {operation} {secondValue}</div>
    
          <div className="number-inputs">
            <input onChange={(e) => setFirstValue(e.target.value)} data-testid="num1" id="num1" type="number"></input>
    
            <div data-testid="selected-operation">{operation}</div>
            <input onChange={(e) => setSecondValue(e.target.value)} data-testid="num2" id="num2" type="number"></input>
          </div>
    
          <div className="operation-selectors">
            <button onClick={() => sum()} data-testid="add">+</button>
            <button data-testid="sub">-</button>
            <button data-testid="mul">x</button>
            <button data-testid="div">/</button>
          </div>
    
          <div className="options">
            <button onClick={() => clear()} data-testid="clear" className="clear">
              Clear
            </button>
            <button data-testid="calc">Calculate</button>
          </div>
    
          <div data-testid="error" id="error" className="error"></div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Calculator;
```

I read somewhere to do a ***calculator mounts*** which I think mounts is `useEffect` but the class based way? So if I am assuming the calculator mounts wrong, I would love to be corrected on that as well, I only know some react using hooks so I am clueless when it comes to class based, but I think that's what it means by calculator mounts.

I am also confused because the clear functions works just fine, although it is just setting the state to empty strings, it still "updates" the state, so I thought it would work the same for function sum but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Move the if conditions inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (operation === "+") {
      setValue(parseInt(firstValue) + parseInt(secondValue));
    }
    if (operation === "-") {
      setValue(parseInt(firstValue) - parseInt(secondValue));
    }
    if (operation === "x") {
      setValue(parseInt(firstValue) * parseInt(secondValue));
    }
    if (operation === "/") {
      setValue(parseInt(firstValue) / parseInt(secondValue));
    }
  }, [operation, firstValue, secondValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! Do you have any tips on how I would display the answer? Now it shows 2 * 5 but how can I show the 10? But like on the same box where I previously had 2 * 5. I was thinking maybe conditional rendering but like on the : have {firstValue} {operation} {secondValue} and before the ? have something like value and some logic. I was thinking checking if value now includes one of the operations but I don't think values.includes('+') would even make sense :/

Comment: I think conditional rendering would be the way to go for displaying answers. But what happens after you get a result and then change the input again or an operator.

Comment: {value.includes('+') ? value : `${ firstValue } ${operation} ${secondValue}`} that would not work, so I'm not sure, like how do I then replace the value to be the calculation? I do think conditional rendering would do it but the logic im not getting it. Sorry.

Comment: Right now `value` holds only the result of the operation but you could make it hold an object that has operator used and result. I think it depends on the behavior you want. If you want to show `firstValue operation secondValue` again once you change the input then you can reset the `value` object.

Comment: Mmm do you think you can elaborate a bit more on that? I remember seeing that React does not like objects as childs in components? Could you please explain a bit more what idea you have ?

Comment: Yeah that true, but you do something like this while displaying. 
`{value.operation === operation && value.result ? value.result : `${ firstValue } ${operation} ${secondValue}`}`

Comment: So I changed the setValue from ('') to be ({}) and now on my function calc(which pretty much does the same exact thing as in the useEffect but to cal values, like literally the same lines of code), I did something like this, if (operation === '+') {
      setValue({'operation': '+'})
      setValue(parseInt({"result": firstValue + secondValue}))
    }
But it gives the error about objects. Sorry if it seems dumb but I am new to React and sort of new to programming and this is the first time I use an object on a use effect :/

Comment: State update function for `useState` is a bit different from Class-based component. You can set the value in single setValue call `setValue({operation: '+', result: firstVallue + secondValue});`

Comment: Alright so I did this: 
if (operation === "/") {
      setValue(parseInt({ operation: '+', result: firstValue / secondValue }))
    }
in the calc function and in the useEffect too and in the div that displays I did this:
    <div data-testid="display" className="display">
        {value.operation === operation && value.result ? value.result : `${firstValue} ${operation ? operation : ''} ${secondValue}`}
        
        </div>
And in the beginning when nothing is clicked it displays
[object object] once I click the -+/* that [object object] disappears.

Comment: Quick update, the issue with the [object object] was because mistakenly I changed operation to be an object instead of value. So far the final result does not show when clicking the result button yet.

Comment: One thing I notice is the wrong use of `parseInt`. Use it on only to convert the result:
`setvalue({operation: '+', result: parseInt(fisrtValue+secondValue)})`

Comment: Thanks I made sure that now they look like this: setValue(({ operation: '+', result: parseInt (firstValue + secondValue) }))
I still cannot figure out what is going on with the calc function or displaying the final result it just keeps displaying firstValue + operation + secondValue but not the final result

Comment: Everything looks okay after that fix. Any error logs?

Comment: When I console.log I get an object with result 12 when I did 4*3 and operation x, as expected, but it does not. update on the screen it still shows 4*3 instead of the 12